# how to delete dummy content generated by Generate items?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

Is it allowed to ask questions about Drupal here?
I assume the answer is "yes" and ask my question.

I used Generate items (a part of the Devel module) to generate some dummy content, but I can not find any option to delete them.

How can I delete them from my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to /admin/content/node, select them, and select "Delete selected"

Comment: according to your answer i have to delete theme manually,but i mean an automatic way,anyway... thanks.

Comment: [Google ftw :)](http://drupal.org/node/579706) - Impossible to delete without looking yourself, I suggest you use phpmyadmin to find the nids of the nodes you generated (Knowing how many you generated would also help) and running `DELETE FROM node WHERE nid > minimumid AND nid < maximumid`

Or, if you ONLY have dummy content, just `DELETE FROM node`

Comment: @J V - doesn't he need to delete from table node_revisions too?

Comment: Well as far as drupal is concerned when the nodes are gone, they are gone. The node_revision rows will be orphans. You could run a `DELETE FROM node_revisions WHERE nid NOT IN (SELECT nid FROM nodes)` but that really seems unnecessary unless he generated thousands of dummy nodes.

Comment: I don't recommend deleting from the node table manually. There is also information in the node_revisions table, and there may be many more tables relying on the node table (tables created by CCK, or comments for instance). Did you notice that when you create dummy nodes with the devel_generate module, you can choose to delete existing nodes? A simple trick is to create 1 dummy node and delete all existing nodes in the process. After that, delete the one new dummy node from the content list.

Comment: Yes but when mixed with real nodes you end up deleting all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using Views Bulk Operations module: http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations ?

Answer (score 2):

When you create content you have an option "Delete all content in these node types before generating new content." If you check it and set the nodes to be generated to 0, it will only delete the nodes of the selected type without generating new ones. However, this will also delete nodes not created by devel.

According to Devel authors, Devel module is not going to keep track of its generated content, so you have to use something else, like views bulk operations or delete_all modules.